# Python-Sphinx: Link to Section in external File

Tags: python-sphinx, cross-reference

I want to link to a section in an external file, but I can't get it to work. The `:ref:` does not seem to work globally, or do I use it wrong ?

```
..
    File: some_file.rst

.. _ref_section:

Some Section
------------

Paragraph, foo bar lorem ipsum.
```

```
..
    File: some_other_file.rst

.. seealso:: :ref:`ref_section`
```

How can I cross-reference to Sections from a different file ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the Inter-Sphinx extension:
http://sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html

Comment: Man, great ! You made my day. :) Didn't enable it on quickstart.

Comment: Updated link:  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html  (The link in the Jan 9 '12 post is broken.)