# How to create a link to external file section with Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I want to create a link that refers to a section defined in another file.

I have found a similar question on "[Python-Sphinx: Link to Section in external File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794088/python-sphinx-link-to-section-in-external-file)" and I noticed there is an extension called "intersphinx".
So I tried this extension, but it doesn't work (Probably my usage is wrong).

I have tried the following.

conf.py

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.intersphinx']
...
intersphinx_mapping = {'myproject': ('../build/html', None)}
```

foo.rst

```
...
****************
Install Bar
****************
Please refer :ref:`Bar Installation Instruction<myproject:bar_installation>`
```

I want to create a link like 'Bar Installation Instruction' with above markup.

bar.rst

```
...
**************************
Installation Instruction
**************************
.. _bar_installation:

some text...
```

When I run `make html`, I get the following warning and the link is not created.

```
foo.rst: WARNING: undefined label: myproject:bar_installation (if the link has no caption the label must precede a section header)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not able to find your mapping inventory file. The first part of the tuple serves as the base URL for your links while the second part is the path to the inventory file. I believe the auto downloading of the inventory files (when you pass `None`) only works with URIs and not file paths.

In this example, I can build the documentation locally, but it will link to `http://example.com/docs/bar.html`

```
'myproject': (
    'http://example.com/docs/',
    '../html/objects.inv'
)
```